# macOS: Getting number of used inodes in volume programmatically

Tags: c, macos, filesystems, system-calls

I'd like to get the number of used inodes for specified volume using function API rather then using the output of `df` shell command.

I've looked at the man page of `getattrlist` and found the following attribute, but it may also refer to hard links, but they point to existing inodes, and I don't want to count them more than once.

```
ATTR_VOL_FILECOUNT        A u_int32_t containing the number of files on the volume.
```

I also tried to run `dtruss df` and search for the exact sys call which retrieves this value, but I couldn't put my finger on it :

```
csops(0x872, 0x7, 0x7FFEEE4C8E80)        = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 14, 1, 2162, 0, 0] (4), 0x7FFEEE4C8FC8, 0x7FFEEE4C8FC0, 0x0, 0x0)      = 0 0
csops(0x872, 0x7, 0x7FFEEE4C8770)        = 0 0
getfsstat64(0x0, 0x0, 0x2)       = 6 0
getfsstat64(0x7FFD41001600, 0x3B48, 0x2)         = 6 0
getfsstat64(0x7FFD41001600, 0x3B48, 0x1)         = 6 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFEEE4C9EC0, 0x0)       = 0 0
fstat64(0x1, 0x7FFEEE4C9ED8, 0x0)        = 0 0
ioctl(0x1, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFEEE4C9F24)       = 0 0
```

Here's `df` output (notice the iused field)

```
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   976695384 757288824 211770792    79% 2000778 9223372036852775029    0%   /
```

Any ideas where can I find the source code of `df` or to other API for this task.

thanks

Comment: It would be handy if you included the actual text printed by `df` as an example.

Comment: @unwind, Hi and thanks for your comment. df output was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found [the source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272/df/df.c.auto.html) and it does this:

```
if (iflag) {
        inodes = sfsp->f_files;
        used = inodes - sfsp->f_ffree;
        (void)printf(" %*llu %*llu %4.0f%% ", mwp->iused, used,
            mwp->ifree, sfsp->f_ffree, inodes == 0 ? 100.0 :
            (double)used / (double)inodes * 100.0);
```

where `sfsp` is a pointer to a `struct statfs` instance, from `statfs()` like you'd expect.

Comment: I now realized that this calculation also contain the inodes that relates to directories. I wish I knew how to omit them since I care about regular files only.